# Setting up my new 3G usb modem "D-Link DWP 156 in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, internet, usb-modem, 3g

This USB modem has official support for Linux OS(Ubuntu 10.04 or above). I have tried all the methods shown on various sites but Nothing worked.

In the terminal I typed `isusb` and the output is as given below.

```
lsusb

Bus 001 Device 010: ID 2001:7d01 D-Link Corp.
```

I also tried to install the `3g_modem_connect_DTLW2_D300A_amd64.deb` file but it doesn't get install via software center.

Comment: Sounds as if you modem is incompatible with Ubuntu. You have not posted much information, can you identify the hardware (chip set) and specify what you tried?

Comment: I have tried this command lsusb and the device is listed as: Bus 001 Device 010: ID 2001:7d01 D-Link Corp.

Comment: Please help me setting this modem I don't want to dual boot with windows.

Comment: @ bodhi.zazen are you there?

Comment: I do not know how to get your hardware working, just suggesting you provide as much detail as possible.

Comment: Your modem driver is now installed. Does it show up in the network manager?

Comment: No,  It doesn't  show.

Comment: I Don't Know What to Do Now.

Comment: The answer below by Nav http://askubuntu.com/a/536364/17968 works!

Answer (score 2):

Switch to `su` mode, plug-in your modem

1. type `lsusb` in terminal and note down the product id and vendors id
        mine was `Bus 002 Device 012: ID 2001:7d0b D-Link Corp`. here product id is 2001 and vendors id is a403.
2. type `/dev/sr` press tab twice. The last one is your modem. mine was `sr1`.
3. type `mkdir /media/cdrom` for creating the directory
4. mount your device as cdrom. type `mount /dev/sr1 /media/cdrom`
5. open the user manual for linux
6. type `eject /media/cdrom` for ejecting the usb device.
7. type `modprobe usbserial vendor=0x2001 product=0xa403` for switching your device to modem (please pay attention to give your product and vendor id which was noticed by you in step 1)

   Wait for some seconds or disable and enable networking.

You can see your mobile broadband connection enable it and configure it with the help of manual which you opened in step 5

you have to mount the device to cdrom and eject it each time when you plug-in/reboot your system

Thats it..! you can see your d-link dwp modem blinking... but it may shows no range , never mind. you are connected now.!!!

Comment: I don't know who down voted this... But it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked in Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 15.04 (Lubuntu).

1. run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove modemmanager
   sudo apt-get install modemmanager modem-manager-gui
   ```
2. run `./install.sh`  (from LinuxModemShell folder of dlink drive)
3. run `./bin/RemoveModemManager.sh` (from LinuxModemShell folder of
   dlink drive)
4. When you open modem-manager-gui app, you should see device detected in modem-manager-gui.

Also you may need to try **modprobe usbserial** command to detect your modem

Answer (score 0):

Oh don't worry! you can activate your 3g modem all you have to do is fresh install ubuntu 14.04 and plug and play support is provided for newer 3G cards. I have a D-Link DWP-156 with BSNL sim and it works like breeze also install modem-manager-gui for sending sms and USSD codes. Cheers