# How to find the driver of my modem

Tags: drivers, ubuntu-drivers

I am in a big problem.

I have bought a D link modem  with code DWP 157. Though I have connected it with my laptop, the green light is there but it is not connected to the internet.

I ran `sudo lshw -C network` and found my device in the list.

But still there is no connection listed in the Networking option.

It is also written in the cover that it is compatible with ubuntu 10.04 and higher.

What should I do? How can I find the driver of my modem?

Comment: What type of Modem is this? I assume USB! Which Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/446579/setting-up-my-new-3g-usb-modem-d-link-dwp-156-in-ubuntu-13-10 and/or http://askubuntu.com/questions/426540/3g-d-link-dwm-157-modem-install-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: It is 14.04 ubuntu. Usb modem @konrad

Comment: Please add this to your Question! Did you look at the links?